# Draw a sprite over the CameraCaptureTask in WP7 (XNA or Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

In WP7, is it possible to render something over the camera? maybe with the CameraCaptureTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `Basic Camera Sample` provided by Microsoft. It's an incredibly useful sample for learning how to use the camera, overlays, handle rotation, focus, flash, imagesize, etc.

[Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)